# How to remove "More videos" feature from Youtube

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube displays a menu with video suggestions ("More videos") when an embedded video is paused. The element in the `iframe` has the class "ytp-pause-overlay". It is displayed every time the user pauses, unless it is minimized once.

[screenshot of more videos menu in embedded videos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z03ma.png)

If possible [The Guardian and Udacity did it], how can it be removed? If not, is it possible to display it minimized by default ("ytp-scroll-min")?

"More videos" feature affects subtitles and keyboard controls and, in educational or corporate contexts, it is not desirable.

As expected, none of the following suggested parameters has been useful:

- `rel=0`
- `ytp-pause-overlay=0`
- `ecver=2`

I would be utterly grateful if anyone in Google engineers team could help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Based from what you have tried about [`rel`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Revision_History) parameter,

> The behavior for the `rel` parameter is changing on or after **September
> 25, 2018**. **The effect of the change is that you will not be able to
> disable related videos**. However, you will have the option of
> specifying that the related videos shown in the player should be from
> the same channel as the video that was just played.
>
> To be more specific:
>
> - Prior to the change, if the parameter's value is
>   set to **0**, then the player does not show related videos.
> - After the
>   change, if the rel parameter is set to **0**, the player will show related
>   videos that are from the same channel as the video that was just
>   played.

Youtube's embed api no longer lets you disable it.
Check this same issue in [github](https://github.com/udacity/fcnd-issue-reports/issues/325).